# Why User Accounts doesn't open? How can I open it?

Tags: users

When I click on the User Accounts on System Settings, it doesn't open. The System setting window turns black and white and inactive. I waited for several minutes but it stays the same. Why it happens? How can I open it?

Answer (score 1):

You should reinstall the desktop package, it seems something went wrong with your installation as you say "I'm facing this problem from the start of using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS".

Open a terminal and run

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot
```

This will reinstall the settings application.

Comment: I've reinstalled the desktop package.  But the problems remains.  And I have removed and installed the unity-control-center package to see if it fixes the problem. This also hasn't fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your System and try to open the Users & Accounts Settings.
Don't Forgot to do this.
You need to Unlock the Users tab.
In Users & Accounts Window, there will be lock icon at the top right corner.
Just click lock icon to Unlock settings

Comment: I have restarted my system. I haven't found the "Users & Accounts". Where is it? Related to users and accounts I only see "User Accounts" on System Settings. But even after restarting, it doesn't open. I'm facing this problem from the start of using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.